# Bootstrap 3, modal and map

Tags: javascript, google-maps, dictionary, twitter-bootstrap-3, modal-dialog

I'm developing a website for an enterprise and on their agencies page. Ihave put maps for its localisation. Maps are visible  in full screen and there's a responsive mode for tablets and smartphones.

Here is my problem:

There is a button for open the map in a modal and we can see only one third or less of the map (or if you resize the window or open the console, but that's logical). I have looked on Stack and other website and find others guys who have the same problem but can't find issue in my js. How can I use the "google.maps.event.trigger(map, 'resize')".

Here is the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Azyme/p7a4fkzL/1/) and the code below

```
    function initialize()
{
    var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(49.0931702,6.083775599999967);
    var latlng1 = new google.maps.LatLng(48.691925, 6.175345200000038);
    var latlng2 = new google.maps.LatLng(48.1116311, 5.13722800000005);
    var myOptions =
    {
        zoom: 18,
        center: latlng,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.EARTH
    };
    var myOptions2 =
    {
        zoom: 18,
        center: latlng,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.EARTH
    };
    var myOptions3 =
    {
        zoom: 18,
        center: latlng1,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.EARTH
    };
    var myOptions4 =
    {
        zoom: 18,
        center: latlng1,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.EARTH
    };
        var myOptions5 =
    {
        zoom: 18,
        center: latlng2,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.EARTH
    };
        var myOptions6 =
    {
        zoom: 18,
        center: latlng2,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.EARTH
    };
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), myOptions);
    var map2 = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas_2"), myOptions2);
    var map3 = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas_3"), myOptions3);
    var map4 = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas_4"), myOptions4);
    var map5 = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas_5"), myOptions5);
    var map6 = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas_6"), myOptions6);

google.maps.event.trigger(map, 'resize')
google.maps.event.trigger(map2, 'resize')
google.maps.event.trigger(map3, 'resize')
google.maps.event.trigger(map4, 'resize')
google.maps.event.trigger(map5, 'resize')
google.maps.event.trigger(map6, 'resize')
}
```

Let me know if any more clarification needed.

Answer (score 0):

You should call `google.maps.event.trigger(map, "resize")` once the animation for the modal is complete.

In your Javascript, first change `show.bs.modal` to `shown.bs.modal` in your `$(document).on` code. That is the correct name in Bootstrap 3. Next, call `initialize()` from inside `shown.bs.modal`.

Comment: It works, here is the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Azyme/p7a4fkzL/18/) completed, thanks for your fast answer

Comment: Glad it works. Please mark this as the correct answer to guide people with the same question.